# Accuracy of a telescope, measurement without systematic error

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, error, measurement-error

I got these values from the measurement:

20.1,
20.2,
19.9,
20,
20.5,
20.5,
20,
19.8,
19.9,
20

I know that the actual distance is 20 km and the error of the measurement is not affected by the systematic error.  What is the accuracy of a telescope? [Answer is: $\sigma^2 = 0.061$]
How to calculate it?

Comment: You're right , I missed the last value: it was 20. Now it's OK... 0.61 divided by 10 equals 0.061... Why do I divide by _n_ and not _(n-1)_? .......... Because there is no systematic error,  there is no need for Bessel's correction ?

Comment: Yes, it's just an excercise of the course Probability and Statistics taught at a university

Comment: @Procrastinator: when $\mu$ is known (as is the case here), the estimator proposed in the answers is unbiased. The $n-1$-estimator is unbiased when $\mu$ is estimated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable thing to do would be to:

```
1) Subtract 20 from every observation you have, this will give you the errors
2) Square every error
3) Sum up the squared errors
4) Divide the sum of squared errors by the number of observations
```

or

$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - 20)^2 $

However, when I try this, I don't get the right answer. I get:

sum_of_squared_errors = 0.61
divide that by the number of (observations = 9)
I get: `0.067`

Answer (score 1):

This is the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Because you know the distance and you assume that your telescope has no error, you can set the mean to 20. You then get it with the following formula.

$$S^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n(x_i - 20)^2$$

Comment: It seems that we should make use of the right distance, 20 km.

Comment: Absolutely right, I updated my answer. I also do not get the same result as the OP.